# Java - Catching multiple exceptions and Identifying which exception occured

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, illegalargumentexception

I had some difficulty with the title, wasn't sure how to word it more accurately.

I'm having this issue, I have a several methods which ask the user for 3 `Double` inputs.
For each input it checks if it's valid (for example if its a positive value), if it's not it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. Now I made a Tester class to check if the methods are working properly. It's supposed to catch the exception thrown by the methods and re-ask the user for the input which caused that specific exception.

All 3 methods throw and `IllegalArgumentException` but the error message is different for each one. Is there anyway (when catching the exception) to see which input cause the error? Here's a sample of my code:

```
public class account
{
   double value;
   public account(double initialValue)
   {
      if (initialValue < 0)
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial value cannot be negative.");
      }
      value = initialValue;
   }
   public add(double addValue)
   {
      if (addValue < 0)
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Added value cannot be negative.");
      }
      value = value + addValue;
   }
}
```

and the tester class would be something like:

```
public class accountTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      try
      {
         double initialValue = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter initial value"));
         account acc = new account(initialValue);

         double addValue = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value to add"));
         acc.add(addValue);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Wrong ammount");
         initialValue = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Re-enter ammount"));
    }
}
```

So what would I have to change in the tester class to throw that code only if the `IllegalArgumentException` is "Initial value cannot be negative."

Sorry if I made this hard to understand.

EDIT: According to my prof, we're supposed to use do

```
String error = e.toString;
if (error.contains("Added value cannot be negative.")
{
    //DO CODE FOR FIRST ERROR
}
```

I know this isn't the most proper way of doing it though.

Comment: So to clarify, are there other reasons the `IllegalArgumentException` might be thrown in your code? Besides "initial value cannot be negative"? I'm sure there's an easier way, but you could always make your own exception class which inherits from IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html - `getMessage()`

Comment: Ew.  Trying to parse the exception message to identify it is smelly.  Do you have control over the code that throws the exception, and can you make it throw a sub-exception type?

Comment: @prelic yes, just expanded the code a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Unfortunately not :(, I can only edit the tester class at this point.

Comment: @Chris - There's always `GetCause()` which returns a `Throwable` cause...but that cause has to also get set, so idk if that would work either.

Comment: Well I figured out how I am supposed  to do it (this is a small part of an assignment I have). According to my prof, he wants us to do something like

`String error = e.toString;`
and then compare the Strings with the error sent by the other method
using equals, or containts, etc.

I know this isn't the "correct" way of doing it but I'll stick to his rules for this assignment. Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't match over `Strings` like you would do in a functional language you have to provide three different kind of objects if you want to be able to distinguish them using the *try-catch* mechanics.

Or with a simplified approach attach a parameter to the exception so that you can use just a `catch` clause but you could behave differently. Something like

```
class MyIllegalArgumentException extends IllegalArgumentException {
  public int whichParameter;

  public MyIllegalArgumentException(String string, int which) {
    super(string);
    whichParameter = which;
  }
}
```

now you can:

```
catch (MyIllegalArgumentException e) {
  if (e.whichParameter == 0)
    ..
  else if (e.whichParameter == 1)
    ..
}
```

You could also check the string for equality but this would be really not a good design choice, you could also have many *try-catch* blocks but this is not always possible.

After having expanded your code the solution is easy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    double initialValue = ...
    account acc = new account(initialValue);
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     ...
   }

   try {    
     double addValue = ...
     acc.add(addValue);
   } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Wrong ammount");
         initialValue = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Re-enter ammount"));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround each method call with its own try/catch block?

Comment: @Chris Exactly. Do that *in the tester class.*

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block you should only catch IllegalArgumentException.  Then what you can do is invoke the `getMessage()` function which will enable you to do a very simple String.equals call.